# How to confirm setup intent for stripe in a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

how can i confirm a setup intent for stripe in a Fragment now that onActivityResult has been deprecated and replaced with activity result launcher? How do you pass that to stripe? Where do i need to add stripe.onSetupResult?

```
ConfirmSetupIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams
                                .create(paymentMethodParams, clientSecret);
stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has revised the docs regarding Android development to use the newer launcher methods.  This appears to be a large enough change that it’s not as simple as changing one function call for another.  Take a look at the new docs here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=android&ui=payment-sheet#android-collect-payment-details

The change to the SDK is pretty significant.  In order to dig into the changes try reviewing the this PR.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/commit/8b77ca2487a01f786cf845e5f644b98460036708

When I look at the StripeIntentActivity.kt I can see on line 160 they revised the `stripe.confirmSetupIntent` to use `paymentLauncher.confirm` instead.  I think the code changes there might help you figure out how to reconfigure your Fragment.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I had a chat with someone from their support team and they said that the new Activity Result Api has changes the way the stripe.confirmSetupIntent works in a Fragment. They will make the changes and update the SDK soon. Payment Intent is easier to do cause it uses a launch function already. Anyway, i created a new activity page that has the custom card widget in it, so problem solved for now. I will have a look later to see if they have done those changes and modify my code.