# How to get setup result from stripe in a Fragment?

Tags: java, stripe-payments, card

How do i get the response from stripe with the new Activity Result Api? I create a new card and i want to attach it to a stripe account. To do that i have to use the confirm setup intent and wait for the answer from stripe. But how do i register this one with the new Api? This is my code and but the onActivityResult has been deprecated now. I know how to use it for picking images or making phone calls and other that can use the launch function of the register activity. I don't want to do this on the server side because if the card needs 3D secure webview stripe handles that automatically.

```
ConfirmSetupIntentParams confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams
                                .create(paymentMethodParams, clientSecret);
                        stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams);
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        stripe.onSetupResult(requestCode, data, new ApiResultCallback<SetupIntentResult>() {
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to confirm setup intent for stripe in a Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322508/how-to-confirm-setup-intent-for-stripe-in-a-fragment)

Comment: That is also mine :). But i solved this by creating a new activity page to hold the custom card widget.